# Formulario al ser enviado no hace nada y sale error 304 http

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http

Tengo un formulario que envía cierta información y una imagen en el, pero cuando lo envío no pasa nada y falla con el error:

```
[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
```

Tengo otro formulario que hace completamente lo mismo, y que funciona normal, lo copie y lo pegue cambiando solamente el nombre de sus variables pero no funciona.

Esta es la etiqueta form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="form-insArtista" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Y este es el js donde estoy intentando enviar la información conjuntamente con su formulario completo, el cual no envía nada, ni un input.

```js
$('#form-insArtista').on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Si"); // Ni si quiera muestra esta alerta 
    /*$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.validator.setDefaults({
                submitHandler: function () {
                    document.getElementById("overlay-insartist").innerHTML = "<div class='overlay d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'><i class='fas fa-2x fa-sync fa-spin'></i></div>";
                }
            });
            $('#form-insArtista').validate({
                rules: {
                    txtartistname: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    txtcountry: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    txtmail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    txtphone: {
                        number: true
                    },
                    txtcel: {
                        number: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    txtartistname: {
                        required: "Inserte el nombre del artista.",
                    },
                    txtcountry: {
                        required: "Inserte el país del artista.",
                    },
                    txtmail: {
                        required: "Insert el mail del artista.",
                        number: "Inserte un correo valido."
                    },
                    txtphone: {
                        number: "Inserte numero telefónico válido (ex. 0000 0000)"
                    },
                    txtcel: {
                        number: "Inserte un numero celular válido (ex. 0000 0000)",
                    },
                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
                    element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
                },
                highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
                }
            });
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../assets/php/insert/artist.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            //alert(response);
            $('#modal-insartist').modal('hide');
            toastr.success('Correcto.');
            $("#gallery-artist").load(" #gallery-artist");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            toastr.danger('Error.');
        },
        complete:function(){
            document.getElementById("overlay-insartist").innerHTML = '<div></div>';
        }
    });*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="form-insArtista" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img src="../assets/img/artistas/defaultimg.webp" class="avatar rounded img-thumbnail" style="width: 100%;height: 200px; object-fit: contain;">
        <h6>Subir retrato del artista</h6>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="custom-file" style="text-align: initial;">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="imgfotoartista" name="imgfotoartista">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="imgfotoartista">Escoger archivo</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="txtnombreartista" class="col-4 col-form-label">Nombre del Artista</label>
          <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtnombreartista" name="txtnombreartista" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del artista" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="txtpais" class="col-4 col-form-label">País del artista</label>
           <div class="col-8">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtpais" name="txtpais" placeholder="Ingrese el país del artista">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
           <label for="txtdireccion" class="col-4 col-form-label">Dirección del artista</label> 
            <div class="col-8">
              <input id="txtdireccion" name="txtdireccion" placeholder="Ingrese la dirección del artista" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txtmail" class="col-4 col-form-label">Email del artista</label> 
            <div class="col-8">
              <input id="txtmail" name="txtmail" placeholder="Ingrese el mail del artista" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txttelefono" class="col-4 col-form-label">Teléfono del artista</label> 
            <div class="col-8">
              <input id="txttelefono" name="txttelefono" placeholder="Ingrese el número telefonico del artista" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txtcelular" class="col-4 col-form-label">Celular del artista</label> 
            <div class="col-8">
              <input id="txtcelular" name="txtcelular" placeholder="Ingrese el número de celular del artista" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txtfechanacimiento" class="col-4 col-form-label">Fecha de nacimiento</label> 
            <div class="col-8">
              <input id="txtfechanacimiento" name="txtfechanacimiento" placeholder="Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del artista" type="date" class="form-control">
             </div>
           </div> 
         </div>
         <div class="text-right">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Insertar</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
```

Ya traté que en vez de mandar el formulario, se envíe al clickear el botón del formulario. Borré la cache e historial de navegador y sigue mostrando este error.

Este es el formulario que hace exactamente lo mismo

```
<form method="post" id="form-nuevaobra" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="container bootstrap snippet">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img src="../assets/img/defaultimg.webp" class="avatar rounded img-thumbnail" style="width: 100%;height: 200px; object-fit: contain;">
          <h6>Subir la foto de la obra</h6>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="custom-file" style="text-align: initial;">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inpimgportada" name="inpimgportada">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inpimgportada">Escoger archivo</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtitulodeobra">Titulo de la obra</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtitulodeobra" name="txtitulodeobra" placeholder="Ingrese el titulo de la obra"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtvalorobra">Valor de la obra</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtvalorobra" name="txtvalorobra" placeholder="Ingrese el valor de la obra">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtmedidaobra">Medida de la obra</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtmedidaobra" name="txtmedidaobra" placeholder="Ingrese la medida de la obra">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" data-select2-id="47">
          <label for="cmbcoleccion">Colección de la obra</label>
          <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" name="cmbcoleccion">
            <option selected disabled>-- Seleccione una colección --</option>
            <?php while($rowcolecciones = $rcolecciones->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $rowcolecciones['id_coleccion']?>"><?php echo $rowcolecciones['nombre_coleccion']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Insertar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Intente hacerlo haciendo un form ahí sencillo y me muestra la alerta **SI**

Comment: Como dices que copiaste y pegaste el código, supongo que el `id` del formulario también quedo igual, por lo tanto ese segundo formulario no se le está ejecutando ese código, pues el ID en HTML debe ser único, por lo tanto probablemente el código se le asigna solo al primer elemento y no al segundo que es la copia. Cambiale el ID al segundo formulario y ejecuta una sentencia para asignarselo a ese otro. O asignale una clase y asigna ese evento a todos los elementos de la clase

Comment: Hola @Pipe así es, yo copie y pegue el formulario pero me asegure de cambiar todos los ID, incluso probé con el formulario que funciona y me sale este error de 304 a la hora de enviarlo.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux Hice uno con 2 input nada mas y pasa lo mismo, ni si quiera muestra la alerta, incluso saque el formulario del modal.

Comment: Seria bueno que compartieras el html que tienes con ambos formularios donde dices que ni siquiera el alert sale, para poder ayudarte. Puedes usar [edit] para agregarlo a tu pregunta

Comment: @Pipe Ya edité la pregunta, al inicio esta el formulario que si hace su función y el de abajo el que al momento de mandarlo sale el error http 304

Comment: Pero ya me quedé con la duda... el problema es que no envia nada ni muestra ni siquiera el alert? o el problema es que si envia pero la peticion devuelve un status 304?

Comment: @Pipe Asi es, al recargar la pagina por primera vez parece que todo funciona bien, pero al enviar el formulario este recarga la pagina pero el archivo.js queda con el error `[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]`. Al querer darle F5 para ver que pasa siempre sale esta alerta de "Para mostrar esta página, Firefox necesita enviar información que repetirá cualquier acción"

Comment: SI te fijas no liga el id del formulario que no funciona (`id="form-insArtista"`) con el id que esperas en el ajax (`$('#form-insArtist').on("submit", function(event){`),  a menos que tengas otro ajax con su correcto id.

Comment: @masterguru Una disculpa ahí, seguramente lo borré cuando estaba copiando y arreglando el código para la pregunta. Ya modifiqué la pregunta, aun así esto no solucuinó el problema

Comment: @LinaGonza Pues con eso arreglado funciona bien.  Puedes probarlo en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/6u7z90yL/).  Ya miras la consola cuando te ocurren estas cosas?   Pulsa F12 en tu navegador y vete a la pestaña **Consola** y mira si tienes algun error de javascript previo marcado en rojo cuando lo ejecutas o cuando cargas la página, pues eso podria estar parando el resto del javascript que tengas, incluido esto.

Comment: @LinaGonza Y para que veas que funciona, he puesto tu código en un snippet en tu propia pregunta, que si lo ejecutas verás que aparece el alert con el SI.  El único cambio que he hecho en tu código es incluir la libreria de Jquery (a ver si va a ser eso).

Comment: Hola @masterguru he visto el snippet y es increible que funcione, lo revisé con F12 en la consola y es donde me sale el archivo js donde tengo este codigo, que sigue saliendo con error 304 HTTP. Incluso borré todo el código y me sigue saliendo este problema y no envía el formulario, pero al cambiar la funcion "`on.("submit", function(event){})`" parece ya no tener este error, y muestra la alerta al poner el evento en el boton submit, pero con este no puedo enviar objetos como imágenes en el AJAX.

Comment: @LinaGonza Prueba con otro navegador que no hayas probado eso antes, o otro pc, o en modo privado. A veces las cabeceras 30x se quedan en la cache de los navegadores y ya no lo intentan más.